How to set updateAuthority for spl-token in time of mint with JavaScript?
Im using @solana/spl-token to mint a legacy token on Solana (not token2022).
The problem is that I cannot set any updateAuthority for it so I cannot set/update its metadata with Metaplex after minting.
Below is how I'm minting the token:
import { createMint, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, mintTo, setAuthority } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { getKeypairFromFile } from "@solana-developers/helpers";

const connection = new Connection(
    clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
    'confirmed'
  );

export async function createAndMint( supply: number, decimals: number = 9) {

const payer = await getKeypairFromFile("keypair.json");
const mintAuthority = payer;
const freezeAuthority = null;

const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer,
  mintAuthority.publicKey,
  freezeAuthority,
  decimals
  );

console.log("Mint: ",mint.toBase58());


const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    payer.publicKey
  )
  
console.log("Token Account: ", tokenAccount.address.toBase58());

await mintTo(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    tokenAccount.address,
    mintAuthority,
    supply * (10 ** decimals),
  ).then((tx) => {
    console.log("Minted: ", supply, " tokens to ", tokenAccount.address.toBase58());
    console.log("Signature: ", tx);
  });


  return mint;
}

example of a minted token: https://solscan.io/token/F87BX1QSwXJsjFsUNMY8rConRa8eaAusFu2xmEKcQkzF?cluster=devnet
as you can see in the Authority section, there is no update Authority set for it (null).
so I cannot set metadata with Metaplex for it.
But when I use spl-token CLI to create the token, updateAuthority is set to the same publicKey as mint's.
could anyone please help me do it inside a JS module and not through the CLI?

import { createMint, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, mintTo, setAuthority } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { getKeypairFromFile } from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import { Metadata, DataV2, createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
const connection = new Connection(
clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
'confirmed'
);
export async function createAndMint(supply: number, decimals: number = 9) {
const payer = await getKeypairFromFile("keypair.json");
const mintAuthority = payer;
const freezeAuthority = null;
// Create the mint
const mint = await createMint(
    connection,
    payer,
    mintAuthority.publicKey,
    freezeAuthority,
    decimals
);

console.log("Mint: ", mint.toBase58());

// Create the token account
const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    payer.publicKey
);

console.log("Token Account: ", tokenAccount.address.toBase58());

// Mint tokens to the token account
await mintTo(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    tokenAccount.address,
    mintAuthority,
    supply * (10 ** decimals),
);

console.log("Minted: ", supply, " tokens to ", tokenAccount.address.toBase58());

// Set the update authority
const updateAuthority = payer.publicKey;
await setAuthority(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    mintAuthority.publicKey,
    2, // 2 means update authority
    updateAuthority
);

console.log("Update Authority set to: ", updateAuthority.toBase58());

// Set the metadata for the token using Metaplex
const metadataPDA = await Metadata.getPDA(mint);

const metadata = new DataV2({
    name: "My Token",
    symbol: "MTK",
    uri: "https://example.com/token-metadata.json",
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    creators: null,
    collection: null,
    uses: null
});

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction({
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint: mint,
        mintAuthority: payer.publicKey,
        payer: payer.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: updateAuthority
    }, {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
            data: metadata,
            isMutable: true
        }
    })
);

const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer]);

console.log("Metadata transaction signature: ", signature);

return mint;

}
I had the same issue try this out and it might help
if it doesn't help, look into this depository there must be a solution - https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata

Using the original token program, you have to bring in Metaplex to add Metadata to your token.
The updateAuthority field comes from the Token Metadata account. Once you've initialized the account as mutable, it should show up.
Using umi here's how you can create it and initialize the metadata account at the same time
import { percentAmount, generateSigner, some } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { createFungible } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const mint = generateSigner(umi)
await createFungible(umi, {
  mint,
  name: 'My Fungible',
  uri: 'https://example.com/my-fungible.json',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
  decimals: some(7), // for 0 decimals use some(0)
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)

The setAuthority instruction only works with the mint and freeze authorities for the SPL token program and can only work if it they haven't been set to null.
ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/mint

thanks for the code snippet, but my question is "how may I create a token with an updateAuthority?", I already have the metadata part as a module which is working well with a token generated with spl-token cli, but when I do it inside a JS module, the token does not have any updateAuthority and I cannot find anything in the documents about how to not revoke updateAuthority when minting with spl-token.

the code snippet you shared is not working.

what error are you getting?
